# How to prove that increasing the number of constant symbols of a first-order logic by the number of formulas keeps the number of formulas the same

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, cardinal-arithmetic

Let $S$ be a set of theory symbols for a first-order logic, and let $C$ be a set of constant symbols in $S$ such that $|C| = |L(S)|$, where $L(S)$ is the set of all formulas generated by $S$ in the usual FOL way.

I wish to prove that $|L(S \cup C)| = |L(S)|$.

My initial thought is that given some formula (or even an upper-bound) for $|L(S \cup C)|$, I could use some well known cardinal arithmetic results to show that $|L(S \cup C)| \leq |L(S)|$ (the other direction is easy as clearly there exists an injective function from $L(S)$ to $L(S\cup C)$ ). However I am stuck in this regard.

The book I am following is A First Course in Mathematical Logic in and Set Theory by O'Leary. This result is stated in Lemma 7.4.13, but no justification is given, which makes me believe it might be trivial however I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega}$ many formulae, so you just need to show that $(\aleph_0+(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega})^{{<}\omega}=(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega}$. You can do this by noting that $(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega}$ is certainly infinite, so $(\aleph_0+(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega})^{{<}\omega}=((\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega})^{{<}\omega}=(\aleph_0+|S|)^{{<}\omega}$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me to where you found the formula for the number of formulae? I was looking for something like this but couldn't find it.